# Adding click listener to FloatingActionsMenu

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, floating-action-menu

Does anyone know how to add a click listener to this [FloatingActionsMenu](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionsMenu.java)?

Mine is ignored

```
floatingActionsMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(img.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

To be clear: I want when I click on the main FAB for it to not only toggle, which it does now, but to also do some additional work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Extend FloatingActionsMenu.java then add desired functionality to toggle:

```
@Override
public void toggle() {
    //do your job here
    super.toggle();
}
```